# Javascript regex for username containing letters, numbers and one hyphen

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I'm going to check the username via both JavaScript then PHP.

The username can contain English letters, numbers and one hyphen (-).

The username cannot be started with hyphen (-).

The username cannot be finished with hyphen (-).

The username cannot be started with numbers.

The username cannot contain more than one hyphen (-).

The username cannot be shorter than 6 and longer than 20.

```
abc123 is correct.
abc-123 is correct.
ab12 is wrong: username is shorter than 6 character.
-abc123 is wrong: username is started with hyphen.
abc123- is wrong: username is finished with hyphen.
ab-12-c3 is wrong: username contains more than one hyphen.
123abc is wrong: username is started with numbers.
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? What have you tried?

Comment: Could you show us what have you tried already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!\d)(?!.*-.*-)(?!.*-$)(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{6,20}$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jE7vV8/1)

Explanation:

- `^` - Match at the beginning
- `(?!\d)` - Do not match if the string starts with a digit
- `(?!.*-.*-)` - Do not match if the string has 2 hyphens in the string
- `(?!.*-$)` - Do not match if the string ends with a hyphen
- `(?!-)` - Do not match if the string starts with a hyphen
- `[a-zA-Z0-9-]{6,20}` - Match 6 to 20 characters from the range specified
- `$` - Assert the end of string.

Comment: @Milad: Does it work for you? Is anything unclear?

Comment: It works and it's really clear and instructive. appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a lookahead based regular expression:

```
/^(?=.{6,20}$)[a-z][a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)?$/i
```

A logical approach using JavaScript, would be:

```
function _isvalid(str) {
   var re = /^[a-z][a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)?$/i
   return ((str.length > 5) && (str.length < 21) && re.test(str))
}
```

Comment: thank you @hwnd so much.